# Why is this narrowing conversion not detected?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, list-initialization

when constructing variables using the list-initialization (like `int x{ 5 };`) [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) §8.5.4 says:

> If a narrowing conversion […] is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed. 
>    <sub>(7)</sub> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion -
>   <sub>(7.4)</sub> from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will ﬁt into the target type.

So why does this compile?

```
char c{ 'A' };
char x{ c + c };
```

---

As a reminder, `c + c` yields an `int`

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(c + c), int>, "");
```

so the compiler should complain about a narrowing conversion which is certainly not a constant expression.

---

Interestingly, declaring `x` to be an `unsigned char` correctly fails to compile:

```
char c{ 'A' };
unsigned char x{ c + c };
```

> C2397 conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char' requires a narrowing conversion

As does introducing a temporary:

```
char c{ 'A' };
int sum{ c + c };
char x{ sum }; //C2397 conversion from 'int' to 'char' requires [...]
```

---

So why does the first version compile? I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.5 and compile it with `/wall` and all warnings are errors enabled in a `x64` debug build. Setting the standard C++11, C++14 and C++17 all compile.

---

**I filed the bug report [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/613834/compiler-allows-specific-narrowing-conversion.html)**

Comment: clang [gives](https://godbolt.org/z/QRPncY) an error for this, while gcc gives a warning.

Comment: what compilation flags are you using? Are`-Wall` or `-Wnarrowing` used? (or their visual studio equivalents.)

Comment: Seems like Biagio Festa's answer is the correct one with a visual studio bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. You are right: the program is *ill-formed*.

In such a case (*standard §1.4*):

> a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message.

Indeed, `gcc` produces a warning message. `clang` directly rejects the code as a compiler error.

This specific topic has already been discussed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783) for *gcc*<sup>1</sup>.

`Visual Studio` is supposed to produce a diagnostic message (I suggest you check your compilation options. Did you disable warnings? Are you compiling with *C++(11/14/17)*?, ...). If this is not the case, it's an implementation bug.

**Update:**

[Visual Studio v19.20](https://godbolt.org/z/6G8Num) does not produce any diagnostic message (even with `/Wall` flag).

[A bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/613834/compiler-allows-specific-narrowing-conversion.html) has been filled here.

---

<sup>1</sup> *For additional information regarding gcc implementation for narrowing check [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Wnarrowing).*

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using?
If you fill a bug report, I think it could be useful to add the link as a comment to this answer. Thanks

Comment: I actually switched through C++11 - C++14 - C++17 to see if it makes a difference, but there was none so I just tagged C++11 for the post.

Comment: Yeah you just need C++11 or above

Comment: And yes, I wrote a short summary as well as linking this post. Shall it be helpful.